# Tool for edit CSS and preview in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, plugins

I'm looking for a VS2008 Plugin or other tool that allows me to edit CSS and preview the changes in IE and Firefox.

I'm not full time web designer, so free or open source is a plus.
Visual Studio integration is a big plus

Reviewed so far:

### CSSVista

Pros:

- Free
- Nice previews

Cons:

- Editor is not powerful
- No save to local file
- No intellisense

### Firebug

Pros:

- Free
- Intellisense

Cons:

- No save to local file
- Only firefox

### Homesite

Pros:

- Intellisense
- Saves to localfile

Cons:

- Not free

Comment: Some time ago I did that - but does the general preview window within Visual Studio (i.e., the Design view) not update when you change the CSS?

Comment: umm, no, I does not even render any css in the css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use to get that functionality is through the Web Developer Addon for Firefox, you can edit CSS in real time. I don't know of a functionality like that for VS.

Comment: and how do you save the changes?

Comment: @Eduardo: in the Edit CSS option of this tool, there's a save/refresh mechanism built-in.

Comment: It is nice but lacks intellisense

Answer (score 3):

[skybound stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/stylizer/) seems to be the app for you. allows for live editing, much like cssvista, but with way more powerful tools for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer you'r looking for realy but Firebug for Firefox has css-edit-preview.

Answer (score -1):

For Ie-----there is one tool Iedeveloper tool
For Firefox----Firebug is enough..........Using these two,,,u can edit css and u can see the preview